# How Do We Run a Gradle Dependency Report for Plugins?

Tags: gradle

Running `gradle dependencies` lists compile-time dependencies. IOW, it reports direct and transitive dependencies coming from the `dependencies` closure for the subproject.

What is the equivalent means of determining the transitive dependencies being used by Gradle plugins, the ones specified by the `dependencies` closure in the `buildscript` closure?

For example, suppose I have this top-level `build.gradle` file in an Android project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:gradle-plugin:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }
}
```

How do I find out what transitive dependencies are being pulled in by the `com.apollographql.apollo:gradle-plugin:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT` dependency?

Comment: You can use `gradle buildEnvironment` to view the buildscript dependencies, as stated [here in the Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_buildscript_dependencies). Also, check out `gradle tasks --all` for a list of all Gradle help tasks.

Comment: That's what I was looking for -- thanks! Note that you have to run that in the project directory; `gradle buildEnvironment` in a module turned up nothing. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Okay, I'll collect some additional information from the Gradle docs to write a proper answer, since I don't like to answer with one-liners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle provides various help tasks. A list of them is available via `gradle tasks -all`.

To access the buildscript dependencies, one can use the `gradle buildEnvironment` command, as described in the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_buildscript_dependencies):

> #### 4.7.5. Listing project buildscript dependencies
>
> Running gradle buildEnvironment visualises the buildscript dependencies of the selected project, similarly to how gradle dependencies visualises the dependencies of the software being built.

As addition, *CommonsWare* stated, that the command must be executed from the project directory.